# Redirect URL with data tracking

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I'm not familiar with web programming and I'm not even sure what to google to solve my task, so please don't judge me if you find my question stupid..

I have a wordpress blog and I need to cloak an affiliate link. Also I would like to track whom have visited ,y aff link. And here is how I want it to do:

1) I give each person its unique link to my page. (e.g. http://mywpblog.com/out/id15832 where "id15832" is unique person's identifier)
2) Person gets redirected to htpp://myafflink.com
3) Some script logs that id15832 visited my aff link.

That is it. So I have different link to my local page with script which logs ID and redirects all of them to one fixed link outside of my blog.r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty Link Lite plugin suits my needs completely.